# React - change props at child1 with callback and pass new value to child2

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app I have a child component, 'Menu', where a 'select' state is updated by a click event, like so:

**Menus.jsx** (child):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Brewing from './Brewing.jsx';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


class Menus extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        select: '',      
        isLoading: false,
        redirect: false
    };
  };

  (...)

  gotoCoffee = (index) => {
    this.setState({isLoading:true, select:this.state.coffees[index]})
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({isLoading:false,redirect:true})
    },5000)
    console.log(this.state.coffees[index])
  }

  renderCoffee = () => {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return (<Redirect to={'/coffee/'+this.state.select} />)
    }
  }

  render(){
    const coffees = this.state.coffees;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title is-1"><font color="#C86428">Menu</font></h1>
        <hr/><br/>
        {coffees.map((coffee, index) => 
          <span key={coffee}>
            <div>
               {this.state.isLoading && <Brewing/>}
               {this.renderCoffee()}
              <div onClick={() => this.gotoCoffee(index)} 
                   style={{textDecoration:'underline',cursor:'pointer'}}>
                  <strong><font color="#C86428">{coffee}</font></strong></div>
              <div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </span>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Menus);
```

the above works.

---

However, let's say I have another child component, 'Coffee', which should inherit this changed state.

I have learned that passing this event change, and state, from child to another child component, is an anti-pattern. Considering the ways of React, data can only flow from top-to-bottom i.e., from parent-to-child.

So have I tried to manage 'select' state from top to bottom, like so:

**App.jsx** (parent)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      select: '',
    };
    this.onSelectChange = this.onSelectChange.bind(this);
  };
```

then I would use a callback here at 'App.jsx', like so:

```
onSelectChange(newSelect){ 
    this.setState({ select: newSelect });
  }
```

and pass it to 'Menus' component, like so:

```
<Route exact path='/menus' render={() => (
                    <Menus
                      onSelectChange={this.onSelectChange}
                    />
                  )} />
```

finally, at child 'Menus', I would user event change to change props, which could be passed to other childs etc:

```
gotoCoffee = (index) => {
    this.setState({isLoading:true})
    this.props.onSelectChange(index)
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({isLoading:false,redirect:true})
    },5000)
    console.log(this.props.select)
  }
```

but I'm getting `console.log(this.props.select)` 'undefined'.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only passing onSelectChange method as a prop to Menu component right now, to access this.props.select, you need to pass select as prop to Menu.

```
<Route exact path='/menus' render={() => (
  <Menus
    onSelectChange={this.onSelectChange}
    select={this.state.select}
  />
)} />
```

Whenever this.onSelectChange method gets called and state changes in your App.jsx, your Menu component will be rendered. You can use the updated *this.props.select* in your render method or in any non static method of your Menu component.

```
class Menu extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.select);

    return (
      ...
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: could you please complete your answer with updated `this.state.select` being printed within Menus.jsx?

Comment: @data_garden Edited my answer.